# sql is only returning 1 row, how do I access the rest?

Tags: javascript, sql

```
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY points DESC`).then(allScores => {
        console.log(allScores);
    });
```

This should give me all of the rows ordered by points, but I'm only getting the first row.
How do I access all of the other rows using javascript?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And which node library to access it?

Comment: npm sqlite      .......

Comment: So this is running in NodeJS?

Comment: Roughly how many rows are you expecting to see? I'm not sure console.log will show you multiple rows like this. Try iterating them and writing to somewhere.

Comment: @ecg8 how can I iterate it? as in, how do I get the 2nd row only?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sql.all` instead of `sql.get` refer http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/

Answer (score 0):

Define your db instance as follows:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

// open the database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/yourCoolDB');
```

And then,

```
let sql = `SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY points DESC`;

db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    console.log(row.Id); // You can use row.yourAnotherAttributeName
  });
});
```